# Как сделать такой parallax эффект?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, parallax

Как сделать такой эффект, как на сайте https://www.fotonaut.cz/en/ ? Интересует поведение пилюль (таблеток), если присмотреться, они как бы живут своей жизнью, двигаются в независимости от движения мыши. И двигаются даже когда мышь не двигается. Интересует именно этот эффект. Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?)) Спасибо!!!

Comment: `animation`, почитайте

Comment: параллакс двигает слои, в которых есть отдельные объекты, некоторые из которых анимированы через @keyframes

Comment: Я код мельком глянул, думал там канвас, но всё проще оказалось. Просто отдельные img, которые анимируются, я так думаю, js`ом. Ну плюс ещё некоторые объекты относительно движения мыши смещаются. Хотя как на слои разложили мне понравилось. Грамотно, имхо. контрол+шифт+с и изучайте как оно всё устроено. Стили смотри, разметку, код хз. Я не глянул. Может он обфусцирован.

Comment: Эта штука на ножках не работает на мобилке, срабатывает только css анииация

Comment: Да, нужно только для десктопа это сделать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я правильно `requestAnimationFrame` использую? https://jsfiddle.net/tnv2gdq4/

Comment: @hu-fo попробую вечером не забыть :) сейчас на телефоне открыл, но jsfiddle у меня не открывается

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а тут https://codepen.io/hu-fo/pen/OJPYvbw ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это и без `requestAnimationFrame ` работает, но я не понимаю как его в этом случае использовать.

Comment: @hu-fo вообще то не очень, для такого случая лучше подойдет Web Animation API

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  а можете, когда время будет, ответить на вопрос автора? Очень интересно.

Comment: @hu-fo могу, может быть вечером

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вот как вариант. Конечно, на SO есть товарищи, которые могут реализовать это гораздо лучше. Мне и самому хотелось бы увидеть такие решения.

```js
var currentX = '';
var currentY = '';
var movementConstant = 0.05;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (currentX == '') currentX = e.pageX;
  var xdiff = e.pageX - currentX;
  currentX = e.pageX;
  if (currentY == '') currentY = e.pageY;
  var ydiff = e.pageY - currentY;
  currentY = e.pageY;
  $('.parallax_contanier div').each(function(i, el) {
    var movement = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
    var movementy = (i + 1) * (ydiff * movementConstant);
    var newX = $(el).position().left + movement;
    var newY = $(el).position().top + movementy;
    $(el).css('left', newX + 'px');
    $(el).css('top', newY + 'px');
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/SPbeVMa.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.layer1 {
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}

.layer2 {
  top: 40%;
  left: 60%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.random {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.random1 {
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  animation: moveY 15s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

.random2 {
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: gold;
  animation: moveX 15s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes moveX {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    top: 30%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: rotate(72deg);
  }
  40% {
    top: 5%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: rotate(144deg);
  }
  60% {
    top: 30%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: rotate(216deg);
  }
  80% {
    top: 4%;
    left: 70%;
    transform: rotate(288deg);
  }
  100% {
    top: 2%;
    left: 80%;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes moveY {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
    left: 30%;
  }
  20% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 40%;
  }
  40% {
    top: 45%;
    left: 30%;
  }
  60% {
    top: 60%;
    left: 5%;
  }
  80% {
    top: 70%;
    left: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 80%;
    left: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax_contanier">
  <div class="parallax layer1"></div>
  <div class="parallax layer2"></div>
</div>

<div class="random_contanier">
  <div class="random random1"></div>
  <div class="random random2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Что-то такое получилось:

```js
// функция линейной интерполяции
let lerp = (a, b, val) => a + val * (b - a);  
// генератор псевдослучайных чисел
let rand = n => (Math.sin(n)*43758.5453123)%1; 
// одномерный шум
let noise = p => lerp(rand(Math.floor(p)), rand(Math.floor(p) + 1.0), p%1);
// слои, принимающие участие в параллакс эффекте
let layers = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
// массив с состояниями слоёв
let offsets = [...layers].map(l => ({x:0, y:0, X:0, Y:0}));

// слушатель положения курсора
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let dx = innerWidth/2 - e.x; // дельта по X от центра экрана
  let dy = innerHeight/2 - e.y; // дельта по X от центра экрана
  offsets.forEach((layer, i) => { // для каждого слоя поменяем "целевое" положение
    layer.X = (1 + i) * dx * 0.1; // положение слоя по X
    layer.Y = (1 + i) * dy * 0.1; // положение слоя по Y
  });
})

requestAnimationFrame(draw); // говорим браузеру что надо нарисовать кадр

// функция, которая рисует один кадр, ее аргумент - время с начала анимации в мс
function draw(t) {
  offsets.forEach((layer, i) => {         // для каждого слоя, 
    layer.x += (layer.X - layer.x) * 0.1; // двигаемся в сторону целевого положения по Х
    layer.y += (layer.Y - layer.y) * 0.1; // и по Y
    let x = layer.x + noise((1e5+t/9e3)*(i+1))*33; // + значение шума от времени по Х
    let y = layer.y + noise((1e7+t/9e3)*(i+1))*22; // и по Y
    layers[i].style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`; // двигаем слой
  })
  requestAnimationFrame(draw); // говорим браузеру что надо-бы нарисовать еще один кадр
}
```

```css
.parallax {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/41/900/300"
       style="margin:-50px">
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/23/150"
       style="margin:20px">
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/43/80"
       style="margin:40px">
</div>
```

Comment: Больше было интересно плавное движение картинок(которые живут своей жизнью) без кейфреймов и транзишенов

Comment: @hu-fo добавил простой одномерный математический шум к положению слоя

Comment: @Sevastopol' надо просто margin подобрать больше суммы максимальных смещений

Comment: Осталось понять что такое одномерный математический шум ))

Comment: @hu-fo функция, от одного линейно меняющегося входного аргумента, которая дает непредсказуемое на первый взгляд значение, я сейчас запилю демонстрацию

Comment: @hu-fo https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/QWwXLEq

Comment: @hu-fo https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%83%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: @hu-fo https://thebookofshaders.com/11/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ уже комментарии пишешь к коду.Отлично.

Answer (score 9):

Хотелось бы всё же дополнительно добавить вариант, в котором для передвижения элементов в независимости от движения мыши вместо `@keyframes` используется очень интересное [решение](https://jsfiddle.net/tnv2gdq4/) от [@hu-fo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/355286/hu-fo) (за что ему спасибо!).

```js
//Решение @hu-fo. Передвижение элементов в независимости от движения мыши
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.layer__item');
var layer = document.querySelector('.layer');
items.forEach(item => requestAnimationFrame(() => move(item)));
function move(el) {
  var s = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
  var x = s * (Math.random() * 40);
  var y = s * (Math.random() * 40);
  var td = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
  el.style.transitionDuration = `${td}s`;
  el.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0)`;
  setTimeout(function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => move(el));
  }, td * 1000);
}
//Передвижение элементов в зависимости от движения мыши
var currentX = '';
var currentY = '';
var movementConstant = 0.05;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (currentX == '') currentX = e.pageX;
  var xdiff = e.pageX - currentX;
  currentX = e.pageX;
  if (currentY == '') currentY = e.pageY;
  var ydiff = e.pageY - currentY;
  currentY = e.pageY;
  $('.parallax_contanier div').each(function(i, el) {
    var movement = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
    var movementy = (i + 1) * (ydiff * movementConstant);
    var newX = $(el).position().left + movement;
    var newY = $(el).position().top + movementy;
    $(el).css('left', newX + 'px');
    $(el).css('top', newY + 'px');
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/SPbeVMa.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.layer1 {
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}

.layer2 {
  top: 40%;
  left: 60%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.layer__item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.layer__item:nth-child(1) {
  left: 70%;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: gold;
}

.layer__item:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}

.layer__item:nth-child(3) {
  left: 30%;
  top: 70%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax_contanier">
  <div class="parallax layer1"></div>
  <div class="parallax layer2"></div>
  <ul class="layer">
    <li class="layer__item"></li>
    <li class="layer__item"></li>
    <li class="layer__item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Классно!! Спасибо!!))