# Смещение изображения в зависимости от положения курсора

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать такой эффект, как на [блоке с видео](https://www.monkop.com/).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076034/188366

Answer (score 3):

Вот самое простое решение с `transform: translate`

Ещё больше интересных вариантов с паралакс эффектом можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075852/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-parallax-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

```js
$('.parallax').on('mousemove', (par) => {
  const x = par.pageX / $(window).width();
  const y = par.pageY / $(window).height();
  $('.img').css(
    'transform',
    'translate(-' + x * 5 + 'vh, -' + y * 5 + 'vh)'
  );
  $('.block').css(
    'transform',
    'translate(' + x * 10 + 'px, ' + y * 10 + 'px)'
  );
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10vh;
  left: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 140vh;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2885306/2f870555-70c0-4780-a7ab-084b0b5d9be8/s1200?webp=false);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  background-image: url(https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mgQuAR5nNRg/WjfZr2hedVI/AAAAAAAAA3Q/h1Rj_QbN1E4wTZWu4OOOVFplNkWdNgpfACLcBGAs/s640/Terran1.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это параллакс, гуглите "css parallax background"
или смотрите пример с исходным кодом: https://www.rudebox.org.ua/dynamic-background-with-parallax-effect/

Comment: Спасибо за совет