# Движущиеся фигуры на заднем фоне

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, прокрутка, parallax

Как сделать, что бы треугольники или прямоугольники двигались немного в состоянии ожидания, а при скролле поворачивались немного [как здесь во втором блоке](https://acrode.com/) 
P.S.: блок назывется о нас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с `transform: rotate`.

А чтобы треугольники или прямоугольники жили своей жизнью, независимо от скролла, вот здесь есть ряд интересных решений: [Как сделать такой parallax эффект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075852/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-parallax-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

```js
var scrollTop = 0;
function parallax(elem, scrollTop) {
  var intensity = parseInt(elem.attr("data-parallax")) / 1000;
  if ($(window).width() <= 0) {
    intensity = intensity / 1000;
  }
  var containerOffset = elem.parents("[data-parallax-container]").offset().top,
    move = (scrollTop - containerOffset) * intensity * -1;
  elem.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + move + "deg)",
    "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + move + "deg)",
    transform: "rotate(" + move + "deg)"
  });
}
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  $("[data-parallax]").each(function() {
    parallax($(this), scrollTop);
  });
});
$(document).scroll(function() {
  scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  $("[data-parallax]").each(function() {
    parallax($(this), scrollTop);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rate__one, #rate__two, #rate__three {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  /*transition: all 1s;*/
}
#rate__one {left: 5%; background-color: chocolate;}
#rate__two {left: 37%; background-color: deepskyblue;}
#rate__three {left: 70%; background-color: brown;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container" data-parallax-container>
<div id="rate__one" class="parallax" data-parallax="-1000"></div>
<div id="rate__two" class="parallax" data-parallax="-100"></div>
<div id="rate__three" class="parallax" data-parallax="500"></div>
</div>
```

Или чуть проще:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function parallax(intensity, element) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var rotate = scrollTop / intensity + 'deg';
      $('.' + element).css('transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + ')');
    });
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    parallax(2, 'parallax');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rate__one, #rate__two, #rate__three {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  /*transition: all 1s;*/
}
#rate__one {left: 5%; background-color: chocolate;}
#rate__two {left: 37%; background-color: deepskyblue;}
#rate__three {left: 70%; background-color: brown;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="rate__one" class="parallax"></div>
  <div id="rate__two" class="parallax"></div>
  <div id="rate__three" class="parallax"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: правильно говорите)

Answer (score 4):

Это простой эффект а-ля параллакса. Вот один из примеров:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parallax").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("top", $this.offset().top);
    $this.data("rate", $this.attr("data-parallax-rate"));
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".parallax").each(function() {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var rate = $(this).data("rate");
      var thisTop = scrollTop - scrollTop * rate
      $(this).css("top", $(this).data("top") + thisTop);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {height: 1000px;}

#rate__one, #rate__two, #rate__three {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 25%;
}
#rate__one {left: 10%; background-color: chocolate;}
#rate__two {left: 40%; background-color: deepskyblue;}
#rate__three {left: 70%; background-color: brown;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rate__one" class="parallax" data-parallax-rate="1.5"></div>
<div id="rate__two" class="parallax" data-parallax-rate="2.5"></div>
<div id="rate__three" class="parallax" data-parallax-rate="0.8"></div>
```

Comment: Я хотел через `Intersection Observer API` сделать, чтобы трогать элементы только в пределах видимости, но ваш вариант имеет место быть, т.к. очень простой и показательный!

Comment: @Sevastopol' : на весь экран - эффект почти незаметен, а если не разворачивать сниппет, то видно только два квадрата(( Надо бы допилить ;-)

Comment: там вроде бы другой эффект - там треугольник поворачивается - в зависимости от прокрутки ...и там кстати твои clip-path css очень кстати - хотя там svg на фоне

Comment: там же треугольники а у тебя квадратики - верно ? вот на clip-path эти треугольники как два пальца об асфальт ...я на clip-path css редко угораю и по этому для связки речи сказал твой clip-path - :))

Comment: @Sevastopol' я имел ввиду, на том сайте если проскролить немного будет блок, который меняет цвет и этом блоке треугольники которые шевелятся и при скроле поворачиваются. Как тот цветоной блок сделать, с треугольниками внутри или квадратами